# Organize controllers into folder in Play (Scala) framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I wonder whether it's possible to organize controllers generated by the Play framework into a folder (for example 'controllers') like in Rails? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you mean by generated, but you can organize your own controllers into **Java packages**.

I haven't tried that in Scala, but in Java you can put your controllers (extending `play.mvc.Controller`) into subpackages of `controllers`.

```
|- controllers
|--- Application.java
|- controllers.admin
|--- Admin.java
```

If your are not familiar with Java packages, they are **organized in a folder structure**, so the `controllers.admin`-package has the path `app/controllers/admin/` in your Play project.

In your project or view files you address these controllers with the package before the class name.

```
# Path: conf/routes
GET /admin             admin.Admin.index
```

... or ...

```
*{ 
     Path: app/views/admin/Admin/index.html (app/views/<package>/<Controller>/<method>
}*

#{form @admin.Admin.setSomething()} 
    ...
#{/form}
```

Comment: you can do the same thing for scala. different packages, different directories. I think the root directory must be called controllers, but you can create your tree inside as you like.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I am pretty sure that the play routing uses `controllers` as its root by convention.